# Live encoding PCM MU-LAW (mlaw) audio stream to mp4

Tags: android, encoding, live-streaming, codec

I want to stream the live feed from my IP camera in an android app I'm building. The video stream's codec is H264 MPEG-4, which is supported by Android, but the audio stream's codec is PCM MU-LAW (mlwa) which is not supported by Android.

When I try to stream the live feed in my app, I get these errors:

- MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
- MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648).

When I try streaming this instead: "rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov", I get no error.

1. Am I right to suspect that the audio compression format the probable cause of these errors?
2. Is there a way to do a live encoding of the video stream I receive from my camera to get it to a format supported by Android and be able to stream it in my app?

Edit: After a lot of research on the subject, I think the best bet is to try with a camera that has the right encoding. I found an Amcrest camera that supports aac encoding, hopefully, that will solve the problem.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251782/decode-g711pcm-u-law